# Kohana template $content variable shows nothing

Tags: templates, kohana

I have a Kohana controller that extends Kohana template class. The Kohana template class has

```
const CONTENT_KEY = 'content';
```

In this controller I have declared the template view to be used:

```
public $template = 'homepage_template';
```

Also in this controller I have some methods, and some associated views.

Having all these, when I `echo $content` in the **homepage_template** view, nothing shows (no content from the views that belong to the actions from this controller). (I have auto_render true in the actions). What can be the cause for that?

Comment: What version of Kohana is this? Can you give more specific file paths within your application? Have you checked the webserver error log for any silent errors?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what 'Kohana template' class you are using? Do you mean the Kohana Template Controller? If so, are you actually setting the content view var in your actions? eg: $this->template->content = View::factory('whatever'). Also, as Lethargy mentioned, it would be useful to know the Kohana version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how I use Template Controller, hope it will help:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Template_Default extends Controller_Template
{
    public $template = 'templates/default';

    protected $auth;

    protected $user;

    public function before()
    {
        parent::before();

        Session::instance();

        $this->auth = Auth::instance();     

        if (($this->user = $this->auth->get_user()) === FALSE)
        {
            $this->user = ORM::factory('user');
        }

        if($this->auto_render)
        {
            $this->template->title            = '';
            $this->template->meta_keywords    = '';
            $this->template->meta_description = '';
            $this->template->meta_copywrite   = '';
            $this->template->header           = '';
            $this->template->content          = '';
            $this->template->footer           = '';
            $this->template->styles           = array();
            $this->template->scripts          = array();
            $this->template->bind_global('user', $this->user);
        }
    }

    public function after()
    {
        if($this->auto_render)
        {
                $styles                  = array('css/default.css' => 'screen', 'css/reset.css' => 'screen');
                $scripts                 = array('js/infieldlabel.js', 'js/menu.js', 'js/jquery.js');

                $this->template->styles  = array_reverse(array_merge($this->template->styles, $styles));
                $this->template->scripts = array_reverse(array_merge($this->template->scripts, $scripts));
            }

        parent::after();
    }
} // End Controller_Template_Default
```

P.S. you shouldn't use constant for content.
Extend your controller from Controller_TEemplate_Default and bind it like $this->template->content = View::factory('path to the view');